# We can assume that no point of $X$ is a frontier point of $R_1\cup\dots\cup R_s$ by this exercise. But why?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus

I am reading "Multivariable Mathematics" by Theodore Shifrin.

> **Definition** $\,\,\,$ We say $X\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ has ($n$-dimensional) *volume zero* if for every $\epsilon>0$, there are finitely many rectangles $R_1,\dots,R_s$ so that $X\subset R_1\cup\dots\cup R_s$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{s}\operatorname{vol}(R_i)<\epsilon.$

Suppose that $X\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ has volume zero.
Let $R_1,\dots,R_s$ be rectangles so that $X\subset R_1\cup\dots\cup R_s$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{s}\operatorname{vol}(R_i)<\epsilon.$
Let $R_i := [a_{i1},b_{i1}]\times\dots\times [a_{in},b_{in}]$.
Then, $\sum_{i=1}^{s}\operatorname{vol}(R_i)$ is a continuous function of $a_{i1},b_{i1},\dots,a_{in},b_{in}$ $(i=1,\dots,s)$.
So, we can assume that no point of $X$ is a frontier point of $R_1\cup\dots\cup R_s$.

The author says that we can assume that no point of $X$ is a frontier point of $R_1\cup\dots\cup R_s$ by Exercise 2.2.8.

> Exercise 2.2.8
> Let $S\subset\mathbb{R}^n$.
> $\cdots$
> (a) Show that every point of $S$ is either an interior point or a frontier point, but give examples to show that a frontier point of $S$ may or may not belong to $S$.
> (b) Give an example of a set $S$ every point of which is a frontier point.
> (c) Prove that the set of frontier points of $S$ is always a closed set.
> (d) Let $S^{'}$ be the union of $S$ and the set of frontier points of $S$. Prove that $S^{'}$ is closed.
> (e) Suppose $C$ is a closed set containing $S$. Prove that $S^{'}\subset C$. Thus, $S^{'}$ is the smallest closed set containing $S$, which we have earlier called $\overline{S}$, the closure of $S$. (Hint: Show that $\mathbb{R}^n-C\subset\mathbb{R}^n-S^{'}$.)

Why can we assume that no point of $X$ is a frontier point of $R_1\cup\dots\cup R_s$ by Exercise 2.2.8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the set of frontier points of $R_1\cup\ldots\cup R_s$ is finite. Moreover if $X$ has volume 0, convince yourself it doesn’t contain any balls. If $X$ has nonzero intersection with this set of frontier points, extend the endpoint of the rectangle slightly (respecting the $\epsilon$ bound) so the new frontier point is not in $X$.

Comment: Alex R., Thank you very much for your answer.